# Expression has changed after it was checked during iteration by map keys in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't understand why I get error. My map is not changed 
.

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object
>   Map Iterator]'. Current value: '[object Map Iterator]'

```
<tr *ngFor="let author of bindedAuthors.keys()">
  <td> {{author}}</td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="onUpdate(author)"
            class="btn gl-btn-primary">Update
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="onDelete(author)" class="btn gl-btn-default">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The result is expected, all data is shown but this error is flooding the console every time.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Don't bind to a method `...keys()` in the template.
It will be called every time change detection runs.
`object.keys()` returns a new object every time it is called and Angular recognizes this as an unexpected change, which leads to your error.

You can fix it like

```
someMethod() {
  this.bindedAuthorsKeys = this.bindedAuthors.keys();
}
```

```
*ngFor="let author of bindedAuthorsKeys"
```

Update from the comments:

```
this.bindedAuthorsKeys = Array.from(this.bindedAuthors.keys());
```

It looks like `.keys()` returns the same instance every call, so Angular doesn't recognize the change. Creating a new array every time ensures that the array is a completely new object and therefore Angular recognizes the change and marks the widget dirty and doesn't complain that the state "changed behind its back".

Comment: Thanks for advice! It's work for me, but with a little fix. bindedAuthors is a Map and method keys() return Iterable type. And if I don't convert Iterable to array (I use Array.from()) it'll not work. Without conversion I get empty table.

Comment: `this.bindedAuthorsKeys = Array.from(this.bindedAuthors.keys());` to convert Iterable to array

Comment: The real deal is always in the comments...

Answer (score 14):

My map is the main source of the current data which is getting automatically synced from [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). If I do what is suggested in the accepted answer by Günter, I have to make sure to keep this array in sync with my map. Instead of this, I use the built-in `keyvalue` pipe of Angular directly with the map like follows:

```typescript
<tr *ngFor="let author of bindedAuthors | keyvalue">
  <td> {{author.value}}</td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="onUpdate(author.value)"
            class="btn gl-btn-primary">Update
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="onDelete(author.value)" class="btn gl-btn-default">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Are there any caveats I am unaware of?

Comment: The proper way to use it is `bindedAuthors | keyvalue` no?

Comment: You are right. I have just updated the code snippet. Thanks!

Comment: This should be added to the NG0100 error log as an example/solution when using Maps.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the above solutions but only the below solution worked for me.

Hope it helps:

```js
get getBindedAuthors(){
  return Array.from(bindedAuthors.keys());
}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let author of getBindedAuthors">
  <td> {{author}}</td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="onUpdate(author)"
            class="btn gl-btn-primary">Update
    </button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button (click)="onDelete(author)" class="btn gl-btn-default">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For me as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.keysOfObject = Object.keys(---)   <---put your object or array inside.

    Now,
    <tr *ngFor="let author of keysOfObject">
    '
    '
    '
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my code.

Unfortunately, keyvalue pipe didn't help me as it reorders the keys and sorts them in alphabetical order.
The solution in my case was to add a compare function so the keys remained in the original order.

.ts file:

```
asIsOrder(): number {
   return 1;
}
```

.html file:

```
<a *ngFor="let tab of tabs | keyvalue: asIsOrder"></a>
```